# how to toggle boolean value in swift for changing the button icon in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

i had done this using dictionary .how to change the bool value in onClick method  while clicking each time . 
    //  delegate method

```
func onClick(index:Int){

   array[index]["status"] = true
    TableView.reloadData()


}
```

// in tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell
    let  dict = array[indexPath.row]

    cell.lab.text = dict["name"] as! String
    let status:Bool = dict["status"] as! Bool
    cell.index     =  indexPath.row


    if(status == true){
        cell.btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
    }else{
       cell.btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
    }

    cell.delegate = self



    return cell
}
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

From: Matt Neuburg Book “iOS 13 Programming Fundamentals with Swift.” :

**! (not)**
The **! unary operator** reverses the truth value of the **Bool** to which it is applied as a prefix. If ok is true, !ok is false — and vice versa.

A common situation is that we have a **Bool** stored in a var variable somewhere, and we want to **reverse** its value — that is, make it true if it is false, and false if it is true. The **! operator** solves the problem; we fetch the variable’s value, reverse it with !, and assign the result back into the variable:

```
v.isUserInteractionEnabled = !v.isUserInteractionEnabled
```

That, however, is cumbersome and error-prone. Starting in **Swift 4.2**, there’s a simpler way — call the **toggle** method on the **Bool** variable:

```
v.isUserInteractionEnabled.toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

why have you created a dictionary when you could store the status in a variable?

```
var status: Bool! = true

func onClick(index:Int){

   status = status == true ? false : true
   tableView.reloadData()


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell
    let  dict = array[indexPath.row]

    cell.lab.text = dict["name"] as! String
    let status:Bool = status
    cell.index     =  indexPath.row

    cell.btn.setImage(UIImage(named: status == true ? "checked" : "unchecked"), for: .normal)

    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: `status = status == true ? false : true` is very, very, very cumbersome. To negate a `Bool` just write `status = !status`. And never declare a `Bool` as implicit unwrapped optional in this case.

Comment: @vadian even better: `status.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

Just [***toggle***](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bool/2994863-toggle) it if you're using **Swift 4.2**:

```
func onClick(index:Int){
   array[index]["status"]?.toggle()
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you are still on **Swift 3**, you could use the negation operator `!` before a Bool:

```
func onClick(index:Int){
   array[index]["status"] = !array[index]["status"]!
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

*(The `!` at the end force-unwraps the value since it is optional)*

To avoid force-unwrapping optionals, define the `toggle` function as follows and use it like in Swift 4.2:

```
extension Bool {
    mutating func toggle() {
        self = !self
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: im using swift 3 .. can you complete the method onClick . toggle it very time the button pressed